# C-string definition in C / C++

Tags: c++, c

What really means by word "C-string" in C / C++? Pointer to char? Array of characters? Or maybe const-pointer / const array of characters?

Comment: +1 this is an important issue to understand, and very few people actually bother to ask what it means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "C string" is an array of characters that ends with a 0 (null character) byte. The array, not any pointer, is the *string*. Thus, any terminal subarray of a C string is also a C string. Pointers of type `char *` (or `const char *`, etc.) are often thought of as pointers to strings, but they're actually pointers to an element of a string, usually treated as a pointer to the *initial* element of a string.

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov No.  R... said it very exactly: a C string is a `'\0'` terminated array of characters.  `char*` and `char const*` are often used to refer to a C string, but they aren't a C string in themselves.

Answer (score 7):

Const or non-const array of characters, terminated by a trailing 0 char. So all of the following are C strings:

```
char string_one[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
char string_two[] = "Hello"; // trailing 0 is automagically inserted by the compiler
const char *string_three = "Hello";
```

Comment: So the arrays and pointers is the same thing and both can be treat as the C-string?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov no, arrays and pointers are not the same, but in simpler cases, pointers can be treated as arrays an vice versa. Read here: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/

Comment: I know that pointers and arrays are really not the same thing. I want to know are there any difference between them in the meaning of C-string

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov Yes. You'll get different results for `sizeof(str)` depending on how you declare `str` (as an array or as a pointer).

Comment: I know it. My question is can i call pointers to chars C-strings or not? Maybe arrays only?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov Call zero-terminated char pointers and zero-terminated char arrays C strings.

Answer (score 3):

A C-string is a series of characters that is terminated by a 0 byte, otherwise known as a [null terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). It can be accessed either as an array (`char[]`) or as a pointer to the first character (`char *`).

In C++ there is another type of string called `std::string` which does not need to be terminated by a 0 byte. The term C-string is often used by C++ programmers when they mean a null terminated string rather than the `std::string` type.

Comment: @Mahesh, It's just as valid to change things by dereferencing a pointer (maybe you're going through character by character and need to change something). `const char *` should definitely be used when pointing to literals, though. Perhaps that's what crossed your mind?

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard (C11 §7.1.1), a **string** is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character, *ie* an array of character terminated by `'\0'`.