# How to count the size of the structure?

Tags: c, linux, struct

In the [man unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) I found the following:

> pathname:  a  UNIX  domain socket can be bound to a null-terminated
>   filesystem pathname using bind(2).  When the address of a pathname
>   socket is returned (by one of the system calls noted above), its
>   length is
>
> ```
> offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen(sun_path) + 1
> ```

The `struct sockaddr_un` is defined as

```
struct sockaddr_un {
    sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
    char        sun_path[108];            /* pathname */
};
```

So I would guess that we can simply do `strlen(sun_path) + sizeof(sun_family)` I don't understand the `+1` they added. Can you please give an explanation? I understand the `offsetof` uses for portabiliy as described

> On Linux, the above `offsetof()` expression equates to the same value as
>   `sizeof(sa_family_t)`, but  some  other  implementations  include  other
>   fields before sun_path, so the `offsetof()` expression more portably describes the size of the address structure.

But this `+1` is not clear to me.

Comment: The `+1` accounts for the terminating nullchar of the string data held in `sun_path`. The space occupied by the terminator is *not* accounted for in the result of `strlen` itself.

Comment: The size of the structure is `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`.  `offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen(sun_path) + 1` is closer to the sizeof the data and +1 needed assuming  a _null character_ exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to count the size of the structure?

The size of the structure is `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`.

---

> I don't understand the +1 they added. Can you please give an explanation?

Here the code is trying to determine the length of the *data* used (or to be used) in the structure.

```
offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen(sun_path) + 1
```

1. `offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path)`  This is the offset up to, but not including, the `.sun_path` member.  It is a worse cast calculation of the *data* needs of prior members and prior padding.
2. `strlen(sun_path)` is the length of the [*string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12203612/2410359) without the *null character* in `.sun_path[]`.   Should `sun_path` not include a *null character*, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).
3. `+1` is for the assumed *null character* in `sun_path`.

Such a calculation is useful to send the *data* in `struct sockaddr_un`  someplace as the *data* needs may be significantly less than the *structure* needs.

---

> I would guess that we can simply do `strlen(sun_path)` + `sizeof(sun_family)`

This is a problem (depending on usage) because

1) It does not include the *null character*.

2) It does not account for potential padding between members `.sun_family` and `.sun_path`.  Although in this case I would be surprised to see any.